# Getting table definitions on the command line in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5

I am new to MySQL. I am trying to get table definitions from the database server (4.0.26).

I tried below steps to get information, running `cmd` as an administrator:

```
c:\> cd mysql\bin\
c:\mysql\bin>mysql -u username -p
password: password

mysql>show database

    -> (nothing comes up)
```

After closing and opening, same steps till password:

```
mysql>use database
Database changed

mysql>show tables

     -> (nothing comes up)
```

I need to check two table definitions. What am I missing?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too basic for the site.

Comment: Something basic are helpful solve big issues

Answer (score 5):

you need to add semicolon at the end of your command.

```
     show databases;

     show tables;
```

Comment: you are welcome. please accept it so that folks around would know there is a correct answer for your question. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In Addition to **[@Lyon's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55873/4846)**  Answer , I have explained with example

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| AbdulTest          |
| ClientDemo1        |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| world              |
+--------------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> use world;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed


mysql> show tables;
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_world |
+-----------------+
| test            |
| test_reg        |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you need to look table definition "CREATE STATEMENT" of table do like

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE test\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: test
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `col1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col2` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For basic MySQL Syntax please have a look at [Link .](http://arachnoid.com/MySQL/)